# Find a differential equation for free falling object

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> An object free falls through a straight hole in the earth. Given the radius of the earth is $R$, and the acceleration towards the earth is given by $g(x)=kx$ where $x$ is the distance to the center of the earth and $k$ is some constant.
>
> Give a differential equation that models the distance form the earth surface of the object.

So if I have $y(t)$ be the distance to the surface. Then I know at time $t=0$, $y(0)=0$. I also have that $x(t)=R-y(t)$. But I'm not sure how to finish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with $\ddot{x}=kx,$ and then, using the equation you have there, note that $\ddot{x}=-\ddot{y}.$ Plugging in for $y$ yields
$$-\ddot{y}=k(R-y), $$
or
$$\ddot{y}=k(y-R). $$
You have the right initial condition for $y(0),$ but to solve this, you would also need $\dot{y}(0)=0,$ since the object is dropped.

Comment: How would I actually solve this equation then? I can get a complementary solution $y_c=c_1e^{\sqrt{k}t}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{k}t}$ and particular solution $y_p=-R$. But how do I solve for the constants in $y(t)=c_1e^{\sqrt{k}t}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{k}t}-R$?

Comment: Use the initial conditions to solve for the constants.

Answer (score 2):

Given that

$\ddot x = - kx,  \tag 1$

and

$x = R - y, \tag 2$

we "solve" for $y$:

$y = R - x; \tag 3$

then

$\ddot y = -\ddot x = kx =k(R - y),  \tag 4$

or

$\ddot y + ky = kR.  \tag 5$

We may in fact solve these equations for $x$ and $y$ as functions of $t$.  We write (1) in the form

$\ddot x + kx = 0; \tag 6$

if we assume the object starts with $0$ velocity at the suface, as if it were simply dropped,  then

$x(0) = R, \; \dot x(0) = 0; \tag 7$

the solution to (6) satisfying these initial conditions is well-known to be

$x(t) = R\cos \sqrt k t, \tag 8$

and in accord with (3) we obtain

$y(t) = R - R\cos \sqrt k t; = R(1 - \cos \sqrt k t). \tag 9$

It should be noted that we here take $x$ to be the *signed distance*  'twixt the object and the center of the planet, with positive $x$ understood to lie in the direction of the radial segment along which the object initially falls; then negative values of $x$ correspond to the positions the object may take after passing throught the center of the earth to the opposite side from which it was first dropped.  Correspondingly, $y(t)$ starts at $y(0) = 0$ and remains postive, reaching a maximum of $2R$ at the antipode of the dropping point, then reversing course and returning to $0$.  Both motions are periodic and, *ceterus paribus*, continue these oscillations indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical physics problem that has a very neat solution. Using Newton's Law of Gravitation you have that at some distance $ x $ the force due to gravity is:
$$ F(x) = -\frac{GMm}{x^2} $$
setting this to be equal to the acceleration experienced by the object of mass $m$ you have:
$$ mg(x) = -\frac{GM(x)m}{x^2} $$ 
$$ g(x) = -\frac{GM(x)}{x^2}$$
The Earth can be thought to have a constant density so we have that the mass bounded by a radius $x$ 
$$ M(x) = \rho V(x) = \rho \frac{\frac{4\pi x^3}{3}}{\frac{4\pi R^3}{3}} = \rho \frac{x^3}{R^3} $$
Where $ R $ is the radius of the Earth.
Setting this into the equation for gravity you have:
$$ g(x) = -\frac{\rho G}{R^3}x $$
$$ \ddot{x}(t) = -\frac{\rho G}{R^3}x(t) = -kx(t) $$
This is a classical periodic motion equation which has the solution:
$$ x(t) = A\cos(\omega t + \phi) $$
Where $ \omega = \sqrt{\frac{\rho G}{R^3}} $. Then you would have:
$$ y(t) = R - x(t) = R - A\cos(\omega t + \phi) $$
Settig two conditions $ y(0) = 0 $ and $ \dot{y}(0) = 0 $ you have the final solution:
$$ y(t) = R(1-\cos\omega t) $$